# Is there a HDFS client wire protocol specification?

Tags: hadoop, client, protocols, hdfs

I'm interested in finding out the wire protocol defined for HDFS client. All I can find is the source code of various HDFS client bindings. Appreciated if anyone can point to a protocol specification.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Hadoop 0.23+, all the protocols were switched over to Protocol Buffers. The HDFS protocol definitions can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/proto). There is also a [WebHDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html) implementation that adds a REST interface to HDFS. But, IIRC, the big vendors like Horotonworks and Cloudera don't recommend using it yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How about release 1.2.1? What is the encoding format? And also is the protocol compatible with 2.6?

Comment: Release 1.2.1 is considered a really old release and (I believe) deprecated. This is also the pre-protobuf version, so the protocol is NOT compatible. In fact, due to a backward compatibility breaking change in Protobuf, the protocols pre 2.2.x are not compatible with post 2.2.x even in the 2.x branch